# How to convert multidimensional array to string

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have a requirement to gather all the comments of posts and show them in CSV.

For that, I have this kind of array ( post-wise ) :

```
 [21069] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [comment_author] => author1
                    [comment_content] => for testing
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [comment_author] => author2
                    [comment_content] => this is
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [comment_author] => author3
                    [comment_content] => good
                )

        )

[21070] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [comment_author] => author4
                    [comment_content] => file reading
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                
                    [comment_author] => author5
                    [comment_content] => hi 
                )
        )
```

I want to show this data in CSV , for that, I need to convert the array into a string in this form.

```
[0]=>Array
    (
        ['author_comment']=>'author1:for testing|author2:this is|author3:good'
    )
[1]=>Array
    (
        ['author_comment']=>'author4:file reading|author5:hi'
    )
```

I am not getting how do I use `implode` function.

**EDIT 1 :** Please find `var_export`  in below code.

```
 $newArray = [
    '21069' => [
        '0' => [
            'comment_author' => 'author1',
            'comment_content' => 'for testing'
        ],
        '1' => [
            'comment_author' => 'author2',
            'comment_content' => 'this is'
        ],
        '2' => [
            'comment_author' => 'author3',
            'comment_content' => 'good'
        ],
    ],
    '21070'  => [
        '0' => [
            'comment_author' => 'author4',
            'comment_content' => 'file reading'
        ],
        '1' => [
            'comment_author' => 'author5',
            'comment_content' => 'hi '
        ],
    ],  
];
```

Comment: You can not use implode on a multidimensional array. So you will have to loop over your items and concatenate author & comment text first.

Answer (score 0):

I Manage to concat the comments using below code.

```
$new1Array = [];
foreach($newArray as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $value1) {
        $new1Array[$key][]['author_comment'] = $value1['comment_author'].':'.$value1['comment_content'];
    }
}

$finalArraynew = [];
foreach($new1Array as $key => $value) {
    $finalArraynew[$key][] = implode('|', array_map(function ($entry) {
      return $entry['author_comment'];
    }, $value));
}
```